# An application of Open Mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

While studying analytic function i came across a problem which is:

If $D$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb C$ and $f:\mathbb C→D$ analytic with $f(10)=\frac{1}{2}$, then what is $f(10+i)$?

I think it is an application of Open mapping theorem which states that analytic functions which are non-constant map open sets to open sets."

My confusion is:By the only given condition $f(10)=\frac{1}{2}$, how can I deduce that $f$ is constant?. Is it not possible for a non- constant analytic function to attain a constant value at any point in its domain?

Any hint would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a different theorem to proof this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29

this gives you the answer directly

Comment: @supinf..yes, here |f(z)|<1  implies f(z) is bounded and analytic hence it must be a constant function. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is analytic on C and if possible f is non constant analytic function then image of f is dense in C but since range set is unit disc then we get a contradiction so f has to be constant function now $f(z) =1/2$  for all $z$ belong to $C$.